# Rails respond_with not... responding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have a Backbone.js app running on Rails, and when I update I'd like to return the object.  I have the following controller that is not responding to my json request.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
    respond_with @event
  end

end
```

It's showing the following in the console:

```
   (1.9ms)  COMMIT
   Completed 204 No Content in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The following, is however working... but it defeats the purpose of respond_to/with.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
        format.json {render json: @event}
      end
    end
  end

end
```

This is showing the following in the console:

```
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
   **A bunch of Select Queries**
   Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 10.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

I'm very confused.

Comment: What do you mean with "not responding" it has to send something, or does the request time out?

Comment: Sorry, just added the console log when I save under both scenarios.  The broken way says 204 no content, and the one that's working (but seemingly incorrect and verbose) is 200 OK.  They are both, however, committing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the some problem. Apparently it's suppose to behave like that. See this issue on rails github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9069